# How to select a value from dropdown

Tags: ruby, watir

Customer Name is the dropdown with almost 30 values, I want to select one value from the drop down in Watir script.

I have used the following code, but nothing is happening.

ie.select_list(:name, "Customers").select "Test"

Answer (score 8):

Use 'set':

```
ie.select_list(:name, "Customers").set "Test"
```

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Selection+Boxes